# Using the replace operator to remove extra text from a string

Tags: parsing, powershell

I have a list of Active Directory group name in the form

`cn=GROUPA,ou=Dept1,ou=Departmental Groups,ou=GROUPS1,dc=test,dc=server,dc=com`

and I was wondering if there was a way to use the -replace function to remove all of the "ou=" and "dc=" sections. I know I could just use

`-replace "ou=Dept1",""`

but I want to know if there is a way I could replace "ou=Dept1" without knowing the Dept1 part, since not all of the group names include Dept1, but instead use other names. I was thinking maybe some way of using `select-string` with a `-notlike`, but I have not found a way yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all ou= and dc=

```
-replace 'dc=.+?,|dc=.+$|ou=.+?,',''
```

It will leave you with `cn=GROUPA,`. If you actually just want the cn part you can do:

```
-match '(cn=.+?),' | Out-Null
$matches[1]
```

In the second part of your question you can replace the ou= parts without knowing the name like this:

```
-replace 'ou=.+?', 'ou=test,'
```

Comment: Am I reading the question wrong? It seems he wants to only keep the container part, so why are you removing it? ^^

Comment: That's what I interpreted `... a way to ... remove all of the "ou=" and "dc=" sections` to mean @Graimer. The question as worded *is* a bit confusing TBH.

Comment: You're saying the same as me, but your answer is different. Your code is removing the CONTAINER(cn), not the domain comp.(dc) as it should.

Comment: oh LOL I see, I misread dc to be cn, Thx @Graimer, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use replace...

```
$myOUString.Replace(",ou",",dc")
```

Would replace each ,cn with ,dn and would also make sure that if there were a group that contained ou for some other reason you are OK, for eaxample *Thousands* would not become *thdcsands*.

```
$myOuString -Replace ",ou",",dc" should also work.
```

Eitherway, you should not need wildcards in your example, because you do not want to replace ou=ForgottenUsers with dc=

Answer (score 1):

Coming at it from the other direction:

```
-replace '.+?(dc=.+)','$1'
```